# curl why token is incorrect in curl but good in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have write code, which creates request using token authentication.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "NQXidyvro-iFzZdtxRllpr1Oy");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

It Works well! I have status 200! If token fill be incorrect I will get status 200.

But when I try to do same using CURL

```
 curl -k -i -H "Authorization: Basic NQXidyvro-iFzZdtxRllpr1Oy" https://example.com
```

I have such error **"You are requesting with an invalid credential"** This error I have in PHP script when token is incorrect. I use same token. What happens? what wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Is the token in the question the one you're using?

Comment: I changed id, because I do not want to write exact token.  but this is not might be base 64 because converters cant mange to decote this.

Comment: What if you put single-quote around the token?

Comment: the same is the result :(

Comment: grep: does using `curl -k -i --user name:password https://example.com` solve the issue?

Comment: The server is not my. provider tell me that only token authentication works.

Comment: @grep Is there any colon (`:`) in your token?

Comment: no but there is "-", like that "FWsQh0ks-f2dka01oX"

Comment: @grep: The minus character isn't a valid base64 character, so your token isn't a valid one. Can you try to encode `<token>:` (note the colon after the token) to base64, then use the result as a token?

Comment: it is valid in the PHP script, I have  status 200. If I change something in the token then I have error "invalid token". I'm sure with 100% that this is correct.

Comment: @grep: I'm asking you to change the token in command line curl, not in the PHP script.

Comment: the same is the result. does not works